# LinkedIn OAuth 2 asking for permissions often

Tags: linkedin-api, passport.js

I'm often asked by LinkedIn to re-allow my app permissions. Doesn't appear to be an issue on [LinkedIn's side](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth-2-asking-permissions-often), so I'm wondering if there's an expiration setting I need to set in PassportJS.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. LinkedIn needs permission every time but facebook only once. Did you find an answer?